# What do you call a hotel fitness room?

Tags: vocabulaire

I've found "salle de remise en forme" but it sounds like this implies something besides "garder la forme" – like it's something only out of shape people go to.

Is this how to refer to a hotel fitness room?

Answer (score 3):

i am an exchange student but in my school they use the term salle de musculation. I think this term is easily understood to be the gym.

Answer (score 3):

You will find different terms:

> salle de fitness
>
> salle de gym
>
> salle de sport

*Salle de remise en forme* can be found, but as you suggested, it would be used specifically for programs aimed at people that are out of shape and want to become fit again, so that does not really fit the fitness rooms you can find in hotels (or, I can imagine a hotel may use this term if it sells such a program as part of a package).

*Salle de musculation* is not wrong either, but is more specific. Such a room will offer primarily equipment used for bodybuilding (eg for weight lifting), and may not have things like running machines or stationary bicycles. You may find *salles de musculation* in town or in sport centres, but it does not match the typical fitness room you will find in hotels.